# Error on navigation menu from term store

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation, pnp, spfx-extensions, react

I have followed the steps from the link and able to run the code on Local environment however the same code once deployed to app catalog, doesn't work. Started to get the error while retrieving The term group ID

"Error: Error making HttpClient request in queryable [400] ::> {"error":{"code":"invalidRequest","message":"Failed to parse the termGroupId."}}"

I have updated the pnp to latest version 2.7.0

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/global-navigation-in-modern-sharepoin-using-spfx-pnp-and-fluent-ui/

Answer (score 0):

so for developed it probably worked as you defined in the `serve.json` the initial properties of your extension. Now when you want to deploy it you need to also pass values for those
[image]

you may either use [PnP PowerShell Add-PnPCustomAction](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Add-PnPCustomAction.html) providing the properties using the option `-ClientSideComponentProperties`

or you may use [CLI for Microsoft 365 spo applicationcustomizer add](https://pnp.github.io/cli-microsoft365/cmd/spo/applicationcustomizer/applicationcustomizer-add/) (which I recommend) and you may pass those properties using option `clientSideComponentProperties`

Comment: I passed the values of the serve.json in the clientsideInstance.xml file Properties="{&quot;termGroupId&quot;:&quot;ID&quot;}"> but still no progress, Anywhere i am doing wrong here.

Comment: but you also provided values for those properties right? (I know that it's a stupid question but just wanted to be sure )
using either PnP PowerShell or CLI for M365 you may add the app customizer providing different values for each site

Comment: "properties": {
            "termGroupId": "3e42633c-2eda-4722-xxxxxx-xxxx",
            "termSetId":"e6aff483-b8b6-4833-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx",
            "Bottom": "Bottom area of the page" Yes I have passed the values to the properties.

Comment: ok so this is a tenat-wide extension? If not you also would need to set it elements.xml
also check in the package-solution.json the assets> elementManifests if the ClientSideInstance.xml is added to that array

Comment: No, it is not tenant wide extension and needed to only certain sites. It is added :) "assets": {
          "elementManifests": [
            "elements.xml",
            "ClientSideInstance.xml"
          ]

Comment: Ok and the same properties you also provided in elements.xml? Because clientsideinstance.xml is only used in case of tenant-wide extension

Comment: Yes same properties provided in elements.xml and how can we use two properties in elements.xml like Properties for termgroup and properties for termset

Comment: Seems strange. from the error message it does seem like it just cannot parse the termgroupid probably because it is null or maybe in some strange format. What if you just try to retract and readd the solution? Also what if you query the properties of the extension using PNP PowerShell? Do you see them populated?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142882/discussion-between-striker92-and-adam).

Comment: Now I see the navigation but I have passed the values in both elements.xml and ClientSideInstance.xml will that create problem when it is deployed ? I have multiple navigation different languages. When switch between languages either one navigation is fixed, How to make hard refresh when switch between sites.